# difference between gabor filter and gabor transform

Tags: image-processing

I have read all possible articles on gabor functions but they did not lead me to anything useful. Could someone briefly explain whether there is a difference between the two ?

Which of the above two is used in image classification ?

Comment: What do u mean by image classification could you specify?

Answer (score 11):

I would provide you certain links that would make you clear about the concept of GABOR TRANSFORM as well as GABOR FILTERS

1. **A Tutorial on all you would want to know about gabor filters  and transform**

> [here](http://mplab.ucsd.edu/tutorials/gabor.pdf)

2. **More information about GABOR FILTERS**

> [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~arul/report/node13.html)

3. **A gabor filter visualization**

> [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2005/cmsc838s/assignment-projects/gabor-filter-visualization/report.pdf)

4. **Gabor wavelet transform and its applications**

> [here](http://disp.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~pujols/Gabor%20wavelet%20transform%20and%20its%20application.pdf)

[image: gabor]

Answer (score 5):

The Gabor transform is a one-dimensional transform used for analysing 1d signals (such as audio data).

Gabor filters are two-dimensional generalisations of the Gabor transform used for analysing 2d signals (such as image data).

Comment: I'm just curious, is the gabor transform (STFT) the same as the gabor wavelet transform?